Selfhosted typebot.io don't load
i'm trying to install and use typebot selfhosted application here
when i log-in the admin panel it just keeps loading forever and this error appears on logs:
Something went wrong TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'id')
    at u (/app/apps/builder/.next/server/chunks/1681.js:1:537)
    ... 8 lines matching cause stack trace ...
    at async NextNodeServer.handleCatchallRenderRequest (/app/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.1.0_@babel+core@7.22.9_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:268:37) {
  code: 'INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR',
  name: 'TRPCError',
  [cause]: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'id')
      at u (/app/apps/builder/.next/server/chunks/1681.js:1:537)
      at async Object.o [as createContext] (/app/apps/builder/.next/server/chunks/9108.js:1:85781)
      at async Object.createContext (file:///app/node_modules/.pnpm/@trpc+server@10.40.0/node_modules/@trpc/server/dist/nodeHTTPRequestHandler-cf01c646.mjs:12:20)
      at async resolveHTTPResponse (file:///app/node_modules/.pnpm/@trpc+server@10.40.0/node_modules/@trpc/server/dist/resolveHTTPResponse-68c8befb.mjs:141:15)
      at async file:///app/node_modules/.pnpm/@trpc+server@10.40.0/node_modules/@trpc/server/dist/nodeHTTPRequestHandler-cf01c646.mjs:67:9
      at async file:///app/node_modules/.pnpm/@trpc+server@10.40.0/node_modules/@trpc/server/dist/adapters/next.mjs:44:9
      at async K (/app/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.1.0_@babel+core@7.22.9_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/pages-api.runtime.prod.js:20:16545)
      at async U.render (/app/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.1.0_@babel+core@7.22.9_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/pages-api.runtime.prod.js:20:16981)
      at async NextNodeServer.runApi (/app/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.1.0_@babel+core@7.22.9_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:556:9)
      at async NextNodeServer.handleCatchallRenderRequest (/app/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.1.0_@babel+core@7.22.9_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:268:37)
}

i've tried to re-install easy panel and the typebot but it leads to the same thing.

Did you setup the postgres database correctly?

https://docs.typebot.io/self-hosting/deploy/manual
